# I am using mod_rewrite and am using a rewrite rule, is there a way for me to get the URL as seen in the address bar server side?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can reconstruct the actual URL post rewrite rule, but is there a way for me to get the URL pre rewrite rule?

Also, when I run php in IIS 7.5, and have rewrite rules in my web.config, how do I get the pre rewrite URL in my php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Apache, the pre-rewritten URL is available in a server variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: Cool, just tested it, works in apache httpd and iis 7.5.